# CSS Sidebar always full height

Tags: html, css

I am busy on this page (http://s.nogax.ga/editor-css.html) and I am trying to make a full height sidebar. 
Basically, the div sidebar should always extend to the bottom of your screen.
(and with it the black line on the right of it)

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r8u7pkd6/)

html

```
  <div class='main-nav'>
    Site Name Editor
  </div>
  <div class='content'>
    <div class='sidebar'>
      Page Names
    </div>
    <div class='editor'>
      Optie 1 <br>
      Optie 2 <br>
    </div>
  </div>
```

css

```
html, body {
  background-color: grey;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  heigth: 100%;
}
.main-nav {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 150%;
  heigth: 20px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  heigth: 100%;
}
.sidebar {
  width: 15%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: grey;
  border-right: 2px solid;
}
.editor {
  position: absolute;
  width: 84.5%;
  right: 0;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

Comment: There are some typos here. `heigth` should be `height`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just make the sidebar `position:fixed` if you want it to always be displayed on the side:

```
.sidebar {
   height: 100%;
   position: fixed;
}
```

Here is an [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGzKap)

Comment: I also want it to stretch to the bottom of the page (sorry if my question wasn't clear)

Answer (score 2):

Apply following css will make output as you expected:

```
.sidebar {
  width: 15%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: grey;
  border-right: 2px solid;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Check https://jsfiddle.net/r8u7pkd6/2/.

Answer (score 2):

For infos and nowdays browsers, you could use `display:flex;` too.

*BTW: You misstyped heig**ht** != heig**th***

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Noto Sans'), local('NotoSans'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/notosans/v6/LeFlHvsZjXu2c3ZRgBq9nFtXRa8TVwTICgirnJhmVJw.woff2) format('woff2'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/notosans/v6/LeFlHvsZjXu2c3ZRgBq9nD8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff) format('woff');
}


    html, body {
      background-color: grey;
      margin: 0;
      width :100%;
      height:100%;
      flex-direction:column
    }
    body,.content {
     display:flex;
    }
    .main-nav {
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
      font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
      font-size: 150%;
      margin: 0;
    }
    .content {
      flex:1;
    }
    .sidebar {
      width: 15%;
      background-color: grey;
      border-right: 2px solid;
    }
    .editor {
      flex:1; /* will use remaining space*/
      /*width: 84.5%;
      right: 0; useless here*/
      background-color: lightgrey;
    }
```

```html
  <div class='main-nav'>
    Site Name Editor
  </div>
  <div class='content'>
    <div class='sidebar'>
      Page Names
    </div>
    <div class='editor'>
      Optie 1 <br>
      Optie 2 <br>
    </div>
  </div>
```